# Does marriage really depend on Kundali and Gunas?

Tags: belief, marriage, kundali

- Does marriage (love or arranged) really depend on yours and your partner's Kundali and Gunas?
- If yes, then what happens if a person gets married without matching Kundalis?

Comment: marriage depends on liking and love of individuals not based on kundali

Comment: You can ask this question on the Astrology SE proposal to get a more detailed answer: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101512/vedic-astrology?referrer=WNGAY2D0NY672-MEPBo36A2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Kundali and Gunas are just a part of the mathematics which is given a name "Astrology". As per the person's birth time and birth place, the effect gravitational forces of planets and stars on those two persons forms their matching Lagana kundali.

Now this mathematics of astrology is **"Probability"** based outcome. Astrology gives you % of probability based on the gravitational and time effects based on kundali gunas.

This is just probability. One may or may not believe in it. But we can never take decisions blindly based on probabilities.

Yes for safety , we can take precautions and can consider this probabilities earlier, but One can strongly change result by doing Karma.

Marriage never depends on Gunas and Kundalies, this is blind to believe. Marriage depends on two person's love. **No hindu scriptures has written that one should always marry by checking kundali only**. Even if it is written it is not a neutral note.

One who is unknown to this kundali stuff , like some christian person or some other religion person, if he marry without kundali, so is it 100% that he will end up in brake up?

No, never. We should consider or treat kundali probabilities as notices or precautions but it is foolishness to blindly believe in kundalis.

Just take an example of Siknadar, who made a new line in his hand and won the world.

Ravan who caged all planets, he was also destroyed. So in his kundali was it written that he will do such stuff? Astrology is just probability, it never gives accurate answer.

Shir Ram and Mata Sita have a match of all 36 Gunas but their marriage is not success, They have to go to vanvas and after returning from Vanvas Mata Sita leave Shri Ram due to some of reason. Courtesy[urfusion](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/849/urfusion)

Any man can change is fate. Only "Purushartha" is the only way to completely destroy risks and win against any situations. Have trust in yourself and your inner values instead of having trust in astrology. You will crack astrology also.

> "Karmanye Vadhikaraste Ma faleshu kadachana", kundali make you bias before doing karma even.

If one who is with strong will and dedicated love can bring peaceful marriage life to her partner and can win against all gravitational forces of Planets. `"Himmat e Marda to Madad e khuda"`, There is courage and there is fear, courage is the only thing that helps a person to win. I am sorry if my intention is wrong.

Sometimes brain and heart's decisions are different. Now whom to follow is difficult for someone. In Gita Lord said

> Indriyas are batter than outside world, Mind is better than Indriyas but inside all creatures, "Saul" resides inner or deeper than these two which is considered best than all these.

Similarly forces of individuals(plus and minus) will affect each other after marriage. This forces can be calculated using planetary situations and astrologies.

Comment: -1 Astrology is an exact science and Ram and sita marriage was 100% success, just having physical distance dosen't mean a 'break up'? their kids were proof of their success(righteous kids as father was )... I don't mean to say that you cannot beat astrology ,you can if you are at that level of love and have some spiritual reason and power(which comes from sadhna any type) in this kali kaal you cannot get such humans frequently like they are one in millions. here is a document with scientific facts, http://www.christianrosenkreuz.org/isastrologyanexactscience.pdf

Comment: @Creator Dear friend, I accept your down vote.. If the children were success, they also fought with Lord Rama... :P

Comment: So what if they fought with Lord they were not enlightened by their mother that he was the jagadpita and their father!!...

Comment: @Creator Dear friend, Lava and Kusha faught and they also won, because it was GOD's choice, Great Prabhu Swami Rama's will. I am not telling that The standard example who is GOD rama or any if incident of their life were bad. He was GOD dear. His sons were also devine. My intention is one should not be bias based o kundalis, he should nutrally do karma as Lord Rama said in Gita as Krishna prabhu. Lord's life was fully dedicated towards whole world, to provide example of "A person living in community", But i am just trying to say is one should nor be bias based on future.

Comment: @Creator `"Karmanye Vadhikaraste Ma faleshu kadachana"`, kundali make you bias before doing karma even. If one who is with strong will and dedicated love can bring peaceful mairrage life to her partner and can win against all gravitational forces of Planets. "Himmat e Marda to Madad e khuda", There is courage and there is fear, `courage is the only thing that helps a person to win`. I am sorry if my intention is wrong.

Comment: I respect your intentions and words, but even with this astrology gives the correct(exact) path to be chosen for a purpose(also warns you for dangers) and with that you can change it if you are such a tapaswi or you can say hathi or yogi.

Comment: @Creator Look.. the same thing I explained in my answer... I just used the word "probability" for that. But if something happens than just believing that only because of Kundali this happened is wrong way. There is nothing like only Tapaswi can change fate. Any man who put his efforts and has belief in GOD can reduce the results of probabilities in Marriage. Marriage depends more on your own love and attitude for your partner. It depend on you not kundali. There are many success stories in real world. We should mainly focus on our Karma instead of planets places... Thank You...

Comment: 'A man who puts his all efforts on god's feet' is a tapaswi (sansarik tapaswi), and he has power to change the fate.Fate, kundali and planets are nothing but the previous life sinchit(collected) karmas which decides your direction in this life but if you anyhow dissolve these karmas by your `'TapoBAl'` you can change fate.That is the exact meaning astrology conveys,it is not just a probabilistic science it is exact science. Even god's have to pay off their karmas like in case of Lord Ram and Bali, they both incarnated later as Lord Krishna and the hunter and cleared their karmic balance sheet.

Comment: Loved this answer. I strongly believe that astrology is probability, actuality depends on my KARMA. :D cheers!!!

Answer (score 8):

**Human character is complex.**

Emotions can be said to a be *Chemical Imbalance*, that can be explained completely by chemistry. As per what scientist have tested on rats but when we look closely *chemicals / hormones ONLY can define Instincts, like Lust, Aggression, Frustration etc.*

These are the traits that are makes Humans to "fall" (to standard of animal). Now to understand the "Fall" here, we need to know what is "Rise".

**"Rise" is something BEYOND Logic, Intelligence, Instinct. Few instance of Human "rising" is,**

- When he practices *Kshamaa*, for his greatest enemy / offender.
- When he practices *Tyaag*, even when he himself need that thing so much.
- When he "holds on" to something, even if every...EVERYTHING seems to be (logically) against it.
- When he practices "Universal" Love, above all difference of space, texture and time.

All the above the above things are NOT controlled BY earthly, material things (e.g hormones chemicals etc.) rather they may affect the Human materially and notice that ONE THING COMMON in ALL of the instance of "Rise" is "Belief".

Now how are these "non-scientific" traits, rooted in "Belief", controlled by gods? (people also call them godly blessings.)

**It's through those celestial bodies above in sky.**

And this is what that *Kundali* projects. *Good placement of the planets and stars give you strength in this subtle thing called "Belief" NECESSARY to "RISE" in a certain sphere of life.*

- *Good placed Sun gives Belief in Self*. Making the people Leaders, men with powerful souls.
- *Good placed Moon gives Belief in the ALL the rest (except Self), i.e Outside World (remember that Moon "reflects" the Sun).* It brings Harmony. As the "mirror" is good, you would see nothing but "yourself" everywhere, because for a Hindu Outside world is just a reflection of Inner Self.

Now as we done with the most high view, i.e 'You' and 'The Rest', we move forward into lower sphere of Materials, which deals with the feeling like "Mine-ness", "belonging-ness", if you understand what I mean.

- *Good placed Mars gives Belief of "belonging-ness" with respect to self.* Making a person great administrator. So even in GREAT adversaries this man would move forward. He, after committing, would never say something like, "Oh mann...this sh#t ain't my cup of tea!."
- *Good placed Mercury gives Belief of "belonging-ness" with respect to rest of outside world.* Making a person clearly see "which share is whom, and how much". He can say exactly what one wants to hear. He would be intuitively exact in business, sharp in logic and good with numbers.

Now we move further down to the sphere of "Emotions". Its NOT about the "drama" we see on media, rather its the subtle trait that makes a person capable to HOLD on the emotion, and rise above his instincts.

- *Good placed Jupiter gives Belief in a human on the strength of his emotional self.* Making him capable to bear anything. He would NEVER let any emotional surge flood his castle of values and beliefs. He is the most "STABLE" guy to be at the front of intense emotional "give-n-take", who would never lose his sense and integrity.
- *Good placed Venus gives a person Belief in strength of the emotional side of rest outside world.* He exactly can match (or even can go further) another person at emotional level. He makes other feel composed. "Generating" Emotional harmony is his prime trait in the situation. So if wanna be happy, "invest" in making a Venus-person happy, and the "returns" would be very high.

Have you ever noticed that the echo of our sound, in a secluded cave or valley, takes DIFFERENT time to reach us, when we shout in DIFFERENT directions? The same happens with *Karma*, which is our next sphere belief.

- Good placed Saturn gives Belief, that "the time would come", when you will "hear your echo". Yes *it gives immense patience* if the going gets tough, and humbleness if its easy. Its only your 'orientation' that makes your Karma reach too early or too late. And only a Saturn-guy keep changing it patiently until he get to hear his "echo".

Now you see every sphere mentioned is paired except the sphere of *Karma*. Can't we do the same with *Karma* sphere? *No thats a personal thing limited to Self. And so can not be reflected on to the rest outside world.*

Also the "real" planets are now done. And we now have Shadow Planets, that deals the "shadowy" subject of Attachment between Self and the rest of the world, which also is intrinsic to self, like *Karma*.

- *Rahu* gives kinda magnetic attachments to a person, for an object. Now if *Rahu* is well placed, this guy would have belief that his object will "come" to him eventually. All gamblers on a long lucky streak in Casinos, are *Rahu's* friends. But if *Rahu* is malefic, that subject will "go" to the "object" BREAKING ALL LAWS. He would the most treacherous person you may see. By such trait he also go to Jail too.
- *Ketu* gives Detachment to a person. Its well placement provides him power to see beyond the obvious, psychic visions, spirituality. This guys minds floats over the realm of common man. He may have great occult powers too. Again if *Ketu* is badly placed the person would be like a dog, sniffing over everything. Self doubt, self created fears, are integral parts of his life.

Similarly *Guna-Milan* is about how well your partner COMPLEMENTS you in THESE SUBTLE TRAITS. That is, basically it makes sure that the low point of the "Beliefs" of the two person never coincide.

So if some couple disregard this *Vidya*, and *if they indeed are not a good match as per *Guna Milan*, then their relationship would be like an UNSTABLE EQUILIBRIUM.* Whenever a potential blow of time hits these couple, they would "fall"... TOGETHER.

*Shri Ram & Sita indeed is the BEST match*. They BOTH complement each other in the BEST way, in no matter what happened.

*NOTE:* I seldom provide references in my posts, because I think looking up to a book every time you "think!", is a again NOT a hindu trait. Vedas were in souls of ancient sages, they have not mugged it up either. Reading Vedas should be a journey of Mind to soul, rather than of memory from one synapse to the other.

Mind you, that there is a difference between Vedas and books of other religion. *"Vedas" are NOT "Holy" as in "Holy Bible" or "Holy Quran", but they can for sure MAKE YOU HOLY.*

Comment: Very nice information... nice one.. +1.... But Decision should not biased based on Kundali and Gunas...

Comment: Thank You. 
In Kaliyuga, "Decisions" are more based on what a person **THINKS he is**, rather than what he **really is**.
We can just hope that these two perceptions are same, for him.

Answer (score 4):

It is said and stated, in our scriptures and Vedas, that persons with larger number match of *gunas* in the *Kundali* results in a fruitful marriage.

So, if *gunas* are not matching in the *Kundali*, then it means there is lower chance of compatibility between the two persons. Thus, lesser chance of marriage survival.

Nobody starts to love someone after seeing his/her *Kundali*.

Comment: Shir Ram and Mata Sita have a match of all 36 Gunas but their marriage is not success, They have to go to vanvas and after returning from Vanvas mata Sita leave Shri Ram due to some of reason. Then how can we believe on that theory.

Comment: I said "chances of compatibility". And rest there are several other factors for assurance of successful marriage guarantee

Comment: @urfusion So you think "Shir Ram and Mata Sita" were ordinary humans. One who Himself has created stars, should also be directed by them, doesn't quite seem to be correct notion.

Comment: @Hindu: bro who birth on earth have to follow all the rules of kaal ckr.

Answer (score 2):

Those believe in Hinduism trust that the Planets in the sky rule the world. When there is movement of SUN from one Raasi to another Raasi, there are changes like calamities, accidents etc. The Hindus believe the Full Moon and New Moon. Many people don't perform marriages or other auspicious ceremonies on New Moon because Moon is weak. Moon rules one's mind and that's why the psychiatric patients behave differently.

This is the age of science. The position of planets in the sky is Astronomy and it is science.
Muslims see the moon's appearance for their festivals. Like that we have to give importance to all planets including shadow planets Rahu and Ketu. Astrology is related to Astronomy.

Some people don't believe in Astrology. They don't see Kundali and horoscope matching. Blindly they perform the marriages. May be they are successful because of their Sanchit Karmas. If they are not successful unfortunately, then they realise that there is some mistake done by their parents or themselves. At that time they search for Astrologer/s and spend lot of money for remedies.

All the people are not alike. The Astrologer can say that the person belongs to which Raasi on seeing him. He can say his future on seeing his time of birth, place of birth and date of birth. The longitudes and latitudes of the place are taken into account. It is science. Even two persons born at the same time also do not have the same future.

Horoscope matching/Kundali matching is nothing but matching of the behaviours, attitudes, friendship, enmity and other compatibility factors of man and woman. These factors give whether they lead full life without any hurdles. Not only people cause hurdles in one's life, but the movement of planets cause hurdles. Why people are afraid of Saturn and it's Dasha antardasha, sade sathi, asthama sani, arthastami sani? Saturn is bad planet, but it is Nyaya Devata. Saturn makes us learn discipline, hard work, patience and justice.

So matching of Horoscopes of two prospective bride and bridegroom are necessary for analyzing their future life. In love marriages may be some people don't match horoscopes. But now a days a literate person is more conscious of match making. That's why many divorce cases are being filed in the Courts. In India also, many people are following Western culture. So they argue that there is no need to see Horscope matching.

In Lord Rama and Maa Sita they are puran purushas. Their avatar is for some purpose. If Ravan has not done Apaharan, she may be with Lord Rama and Ravan can't be killed. We have to think only what is the story in Ramayana. It is only my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: What is the importance of horoscope matching when it comes to
> marriage?
>
> A: Astrology is a science but all
> astrologers are not scientists (laughter). First of all, you don’t
> know whether the time of your birth and all other factors are right or
> not. Sometimes, we don’t keep records and there are various factors.
> There is probability in all those factors. So, if you find someone who
> is good, the astrologer says, ‘Good, it does have a value but it is
> always with a pinch of salt.’It is said that there was a great
> astrologer of this country and he made all the horoscopes of his
> daughter. But his daughter’s marriage didn’t work. It was quoted as a
> probability factor.In all scientific experiments, there is always a
> probability factor – may be, may not be.So we must take it with that
> probability and not as definite.

From a Q&A with Sri Sri Ravi Shankar:

http://www.artoflivinguniverse.org/2014/06/Is-Horoscope-Matching-Necessary-for-Marriage.html

Answer (score 0):

How favorable and unfavorable planets/stars are identified while horoscope matching of bride and groom?

Most of pundits gives importance to 3 things simultaneously:

1. guna matching
   then
2. favorable/unfavorable stars
   then
3. individual yoga and combined effects/ dasha anter/ some people numerology

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! You should cite sources.