# What's the science behind Kundli Matching for marriages?

Tags: astrology, kundali

In Hinduism, it is almost like tradition to match Kundli for marriages. What is exact science behind the Kundli matching?

How people are able to predict match without even meeting people based on time of birth & place?

Comment: Are you just wondering how astrology is able to work in general?  Matching Vedic birth charts would presumably only work if Vedic birth charts in general are able to predict the future.  So perhaps you should broaden your question.

Comment: You may want to refer this: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3394/910