# Is there any method to change your veda and sutras?

Tags: vedas, rituals, vedic-rituals

Dwija varnas i.e. Brahmins, Kshatriyas and Vaishyas use specific sutras(known as [GrhyaSutras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalpa_%28Vedanga%29#G.E1.B9.9Bhyas.C5.ABtras) from specific vedas for doing sandhyakarma, and shraddhakarma etc for e.g. A rigvedi brahmin who belongs to [ashvalyana sutra/shakha](http://www.aryabharati.org/grihsutr/grihsutra.asp?ln=en&bk=01&pt=a&pg=099)  uses it to do his daily sandhyavandana.

I want to know weather one can change the sutra associated with his family and gotra, because there are many cases where the system is long forgotten due to effects of time.

There might be a possibility of changing or reassigning the shakha by a rishi but there are no more rishi's so it is not an option.

I also want to ask if anyone can become Chatur-vedi by studying all vedas but maintaning his own veda shakha.

Comment: Good question!  Here's something that may be relevant. Originally, the followers of Pancharatra were all part of the Ekayana Shakha of the Shukla Yajur Veda, and followed the Katyayana Grihya Sutras; see the excerpt from Yamunacharya's Agama Pramanya in my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7422/36 Nowadays, although pretty much all Vaishnavas follow Pancharatra, few Vaishnavas follow the Katyayana Sutras. I don't know if that's because when the Ekayana Shakha collapsed, the followers of Pancharatra switched to other Shakhas, or because people of other Shakhas joined Pancharatra

Comment: @Yogi it can be done during upanayana samskara ... u can adopt the veda and sutra of the guru

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I think you are correct but can you provide any scriptural references? and I think this is true for non-bramhana diwjas because a bramhana has to carry his own ancestoral legacy.

Comment: but why u want to change shakha and sutra?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Because many non-bramhanas have lost information about their shakha, somehow I got my info but it would be great if one can change it.

Comment: can u tell in room what info u got and what was ur previous initiation