# Was the time temporarily stopped by Lord Krishna during Geeta upadesham?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavad-gita, arjuna

The narration of Geeta took place just when Arjuna refused to fight the battle and was becoming emotionally weak. How did it happen that everyone waited until the whole Geeta of 18 chapters was completed ?
Some people say that Krihna had stopped time while narrating it, If so then is there any reference for this in Geeta or Mahabharata?

Comment: Related [How much time did Sri Krishna take to preach Gita to Arjuna?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9209/3500)

Comment: @MrGreenGold both armies were lined up and shankh was about to be blown. So you meant the conversation was without any pause or thinking/contemplating in between?

Comment: To put it simple from what i heard from bannaje govindacharya, There was pre agreed war formalities before the start of the war. The formalities are blowing of conch and saying akraman.. or something that army marches forward from both side, it its not done both army are supposed standin position till the commander of both army says akraman.. or go head.. even if 5 hours converstion the other army is not supposed to attack until both completes the formalities that was before the war actually started

Comment: In otherewords batter is ready to bat but bowler had to bowl inorder for the match actullly starts, that is why have slow over rate fine in circket match where the opposition delays onslaught by taking more time

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that time(dream time) run faster in dreams, we can pass the whole day in our dream but in reality it might just be 10-15 minutes.

Remember we are talking about highly effective individual of that time, one Krishna and one Arjuna. Krishna is God himself and Arjuna is a person who have worked hard, studied, learned ashtras and shastras and they did lot of meditation and sadhana.

When you do these things, you became highly efficient, and these people have dedicated their life in these practices.

And time is a relative object, we might see time as only going positive direction, but these individuals have transcend the kala(time and space).
Now when you are that much accomplished, your interactions would be fast.

They are also capable to do telepathy, so transferring thoughts form mind to mind. So both of them can do 700 Sholokas what will appear to human as some seconds or might be minutes. Because in time of war, I am not sure if you can get more time than that.

And due to their high efficiency, it might seem to normal people as if time was stopped. Just try and do meditation for some days and you can feel what can be achieved.

Comment: Although, you could be right here, personal opinion answers are not allowed in  Hinduism SE!

Answer (score 0):

Why? Gita has 701 verses, assuming 15 seconds for one verse it would be completed in 3 hours. In older days there was time required to prepare for war. So it can be assumed that they spoke for 3 to 4 hours during the armies prepared. Its like watching Bahubali movie before the war.

Comment: Does it take 3-4 h to prepare for battle?

Comment: @Wikash_ Yes there were literaly lakshs of people forming patterns and formations, setting up camps and getting your weapons ready. For eg say the war started at noon, they could have started talking from 9 o'clock.

Comment: That does not make any sense. Arjuna was ready to go to battle his literally raised his bow so the armies were ready.

Comment: @Wikash_ where does it say he was ready and he raised his bow?? Also even if that were to be true, Arjuna could have easily asked the others to wait for 3 hours

Answer (score -3):

Based on the Book "महाभारत के कुछ रहस्य" by "(श्रृंगी ऋषि in Satyug) & कृष्ण दत्त in present life".

**No the time temporarily did not and can not be stopped, it was just an conversation of 20 minutes before the war** and no one can talk for near 700 shlokas we see in present Geeta.

So we should refer to the Geeta by "श्रृंगी ऋषि shringi rishi in Satyug) & कृष्ण दत्त (krishna dutt in Kalyug)", which only includes the 20 minutes conversation.

If you see only 100 years back there at that time also there were not as shalokas as we have today, so we should always seek towards the truth.

More over IMO the above incident given in the book sounds practical, No one is going to sit for both of them to talk for so long, **Lord Krishna was a great persuasive and can convince any one**

Comment: So you're saying Gita did not have 700 shlokas originally? If not 700, how many did it contain originally?

Comment: Shrungi rushi cannot write it in Satya yug. As Gita was told in dwapara yuga. What is the proof that it is written by Shrungi rushi? How is that authentic?

Comment: "If you see only 100 years back there at that time also there were not as shalokas as we have today, so we should always seek towards the truth." can you provide Sastra Pramana for this?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This sounds very reasonable.